# Select distinct values from a string

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table which contains a string with few codes.

I need to query out distinct codes from the string.

This is what the table looks like (id --> string):

```
578244-->   [Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE]]

578649-->   [Message [code=1503, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=9002, source=FILE]]

578773-->   [Message [code=1503, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE]]

578969-->   [Message [code=0500, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=9002, source=FILE]]
```

The result that I need is like:

```
578244 --> 2502
578649 --> 1503,2502,9002
578773 --> 1503,2502
578969 --> 0500,9002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT if(a=b,a,concat(a,',',b)) as results from(

select right(substring_index('[Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502,source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=1111, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE]]',', s',1),4) as a,

right(substring_index('[Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=2502,source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE], Message [code=1111, source=FILE], Message [code=2502, source=FILE]]'
,', s',2),4) as b

) tablename;
```

Of course you will have to adapt to your number of "columns", and adapt also the `IF` statement.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response and apologies for delay in mine. I did make use of your approach here, but ended up using python to do the task for me for the following reasons:
the data was huge. Appreciate your quick and working contribution here and am accepting the answer given by you. Thanks again!